# Update instance in the first method before continue to run the second method in the same command

Tags: windows-phone-7, mvvm-light

I have a method like this

```
public void LoadProgrammeListFromChannel(TVDailyScheduleParam scheduleParam, Action callback)
        {
            string url = Helper.GetProgrammeUrl(scheduleParam.Day, scheduleParam.Channel.Id); //1//
            WebClient client = new WebClient(); //2//

            client.OpenReadCompleted += new OpenReadCompletedEventHandler((sender, e) => //3//
            {//5//
                if (e.Error != null)
                    return;

                try
                {
                    _programmeList.Clear();
                    _programmeList = DataService.GetProgrammeList(e.Result);
                    // call method in MainVM to update View
                    callback();
                }
                finally
                {
                    // close file stream
                    e.Result.Close();
                }
            });

            client.OpenReadAsync(new Uri(url, UriKind.Absolute)); //4//
        }
```

and I have a cammand like this

```
LoadWhatsonProgrammeCommand = new RelayCommand(()=>
            {
                foreach (TVDailyScheduleParam param in _tvDailyScheduleVM.ChannelList.Select(c => new TVDailyScheduleParam(DateTime.Today, c, false)))
                {
                    TVDailyScheduleParam param2 = param;

                    _tvDailyScheduleVM.LoadProgrammeListFromChannel(param2, ()=>
                    {
                        RaisePropertyChanged(TV_DAILY_SCHEDULE_VM);
                    });

                    _tvDailyScheduleVM.GetWhatsonProgramme(param2, ()=>
                    {
                        RaisePropertyChanged(TV_DAILY_SCHEDULE_VM);
                    });
                }
            });
```

Now when I invoke the command. At first it runs `_tvDailyScheduleVM.LoadProgrammeListFromChannel` and invoke the `LoadProgrammeListFromChannel` method.

In the `LoadProgrammeListFromChannel` method it runs from 1 -> 2 -> 3. At 3, it's not completed sothat it runs to 4 and then back to the command and continue to run `_tvDailyScheduleVM.GetWhatsonProgramme`.

But the `_programmeList in LoadProgrammeListFromChannel` is not updated so that `GetWhatsonProgramme` does not run exactly.

How can I go back to `LoadProgrammeListFromChannel` in order to run 3 to update `_programmeList` before running `_tvDailyScheduleVM.GetWhatsonProgramme` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The behaviour you describe is "by design". Your method `LoadProgrammeListFromChannel` makes an asynchroneous call. This means within your method the sequence is 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> return -> execute code in calling function -> then sometime later 5 and then the callback.

As a result `LoadProgrammeListFromChannel` and `GetWhatsonProgramme` are executed in parallel. So if `GetWhatsonProgramme` needs **always** to run after `LoadProgrammeListFromChannel` you will have the call to move `GetWhatsonProgramme` into your callback method, i.e.

```
LoadWhatsonProgrammeCommand = new RelayCommand(()=> {
    var channelList = _tvDailyScheduleVM
                          .ChannelList
                          .Select(c => new TVDailyScheduleParam(
                              DateTime.Today, 
                              c, 
                              false
                          ));

    foreach (TVDailyScheduleParam param in channelList) {
        TVDailyScheduleParam param2 = param;

        _tvDailyScheduleVM.LoadProgrammeListFromChannel(param2, ()=> {
            RaisePropertyChanged(TV_DAILY_SCHEDULE_VM);

            _tvDailyScheduleVM.GetWhatsonProgramme(param2, ()=> {
                RaisePropertyChanged(TV_DAILY_SCHEDULE_VM);
            });
        });
    }
});
```

Alternatively, you could subscribe to the PropertyChangedEvent of your ViewModel and if the `TV_DAILY_SCHEDULE_VM` property has been changed, call the `GetWhatsonProgramme` from there, although this might not be desireable.